# Titanium Mobile ScrollView with android:windowTranslucentStatus doesn't work

Tags: android, titanium, scrollview, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have a Alloy Titanium Mobile project that needs to use android translucent status bar.
Here is my theme xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now, before applying that translucent status we developed a login screen that is contained inside a `<ScrollView>`. Something like this:

```
    <ScrollView class="vertical-container">
        <View class="title-holder">
            <View class="center-aligned">
                <Label class="title-text bold-text">Lorem</Label>
                <Label class="title-text normal-text">Ipsum</Label>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View id="inputsContainer" class="inputs-holder">
            <View class="text-input-wrapper">
                <View class="text-input">
                    <Label id="iconInput2" icon="fa-custom-user" class="text-input-icon"></Label>
                    <View class="text-input-element">
                        <Require id="loginUserInput"
                            src="CustomTextField"
                            hintColor="#80AA82"
                            hintText="L('labeluser')"
                            onChange="checkIcon"></Require>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View class="border border-bottom"></View>
            </View>
            <View class="text-input-wrapper">
                <View class="text-input">
                    <Label id="iconInput3" icon="fa-custom-lock" class="text-input-icon"></Label>
                    <View class="text-input-element">
                        <Require id="passwordUserInput"
                            src="CustomTextField"
                            hintColor="#80AA82"
                            hintText="L('labelpassword')"
                            fieldType="password"
                            onChange="checkIcon"></Require>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View class="border border-bottom"></View>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View id="loginButton" class="button-wrapper login-button" onClick="doLogin">
            <Label class="button-background"></Label>
            <Label id="loginLabel" class="button-label" textid="labellogin"></Label>
        </View>
        <Label class="button-link" textid="labelrecoverpassword" onClick="showModal" modalName="forgotModal"></Label>
    </ScrollView>
```

Here is a Screenshot of this page (added a red border on the scrollview):

[image: Opaque login screen]

Now, here is the same screen with the keyboard open:

[image: Opaque login screen with the keyboard open]

as you can see the scrollview resizes and you can scroll to see the fields that are hidden by the keyboard. Now, this is what it looks like with translucent status.

[image: Translucent login screen]
[image: Translucent login screen with keyboard open]

as you can see, the scrollview doesn't resize and due to that, I can't scroll to see the hidden fields. Any solutions to that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your root view (ScrollView)

Comment: I'm not sure I can put that in the ScrollView. Although I changed my theme to use it and it caused the status bar to become opaque without scrolling. =/

`<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>`